# Implementing shadow-higlight invariant algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to image processing and openCV, i am trying to implement this 
[Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEcX1.png)

found in this paper  [Shadow And Highlight Invariant Colour 
Segmentation Algorithm For Traffic Signs](http://sci-hub.hk/10.1109/ICCIS.2006.252225)

Here is my code

```
public class rastara {      

 public static double normalizedH(double p) {     
    double scale=(p-0)/360;
    double val = 255*scale;
        return val;
}
public static double normalizedSV(double p) {
    double scale= p/1;
    double val = 255*scale;
        return val;
}

 public static void main (String[] args){

  System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );   



  Mat img = Highgui.imread("/Users/speedSign.jpg");

  Mat hsv = new Mat();
  Imgproc.cvtColor(img, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

  Mat hsvNew = hsv.clone();

  for(int i= 0; i<hsv.rows(); i++){
     for(int j= 0; j<hsv.cols(); j++){
      double[] hsvPixel = hsv.get(i,j);
       double H = hsvPixel[0];
       double S = hsvPixel[1];
       double V = hsvPixel[2];

      if((H>240 && H<=255) || (H>=0 && H<10)) {
           hsvPixel[0] = 255;
      }
      if(S<40) {
           hsvPixel[0] = 0;
      }
      if((V<30) || (V>230)) {
           hsvPixel[0] = 0;
      }

      hsvNew.put(i,j,hsvPixel);

   }
  }
 }
}
```

What i did is converting `RGB` to `HSV` using `openCV` method, i didn't normalize pixels as what i understand that the range of pixels of HSV converted by `openCV` is same as the required in this paper which is `0<H<255 0<S<255 0<V<255` but when i tried my code it never change a pixel `H` value to `1` or `255`.

The last part of algorithm i don't actually know how to achieve that.

Comment: Did you display the individual HSV channels to see that they are in the range you expect and contain the data you expect?

Comment: I printed pixel values for every channel on console, to find out in my chosen image values where ranging like this `9<H/S/V<248`

Comment: The paper says "When the hue value of colour of the pixel in the input image is with the specified colour range specified in Table 2, and its hue value is not in the achromatic area, then the corresponding value in the output image is set to white." But that is not at all what the algorithm it describes does. CIS is not a conference known for publishing good image analysis algorithms, so the paper was likely not reviewed carefully.

Comment: Would you recommend me different alternatives for achieving same thing? i am detecting road signs circular/triangular(red rimmed both) and circular(blue background) ,Thanks